# Replication in "RoughSets" package

Tags: r, decision-tree, fuzzy-search

I am trying to replicate some of the codes to my own dataset by using "RoughSets" package. But I failed to do so.

At first, I am using the codes in the package pdf.

```
data(RoughSetData)
decision.table <- RoughSetData$hiring.dt
decision.table
  Diploma Experience French Reference Decision
1     MBA     Medium    Yes Excellent   Accept
2     MSc       High    Yes   Neutral   Accept
3     MSc       High    Yes Excellent   Accept
4     MBA       High     No      Good   Accept
5     MBA        Low    Yes   Neutral   Reject
6     MCE        Low    Yes      Good   Reject
7     MSc     Medium    Yes   Neutral   Reject
8     MCE        Low     No Excellent   Reject
## build the decision-relation discernibility matrix
res.2 <- BC.discernibility.mat.RST(decision.table, range.object = NULL)
## generate all reducts
reduct <- FS.all.reducts.computation(res.2)
## generate new decision table
new.decTable <- SF.applyDecTable(decision.table, reduct, control = list(indx.reduct = 1))
new.decTable
  Diploma Experience Decision
1     MBA     Medium   Accept
2     MSc       High   Accept
3     MSc       High   Accept
4     MBA       High   Accept
5     MBA        Low   Reject
6     MCE        Low   Reject
7     MSc     Medium   Reject
8     MCE        Low   Reject
```

I tried to use my own dataset to replicate but it's not working. I also tried to use "write.csv" to write decision.table in my local pc and then call it again by "read.csv". But it pops out an error message.

```
write.csv(decision.table, "decision.table.csv")
decision.table <- read.csv("decision.table.csv")
decision.table <- decision.table[-c(1)]
  Diploma Experience French Reference Decision
1     MBA     Medium    Yes Excellent   Accept
2     MSc       High    Yes   Neutral   Accept
3     MSc       High    Yes Excellent   Accept
4     MBA       High     No      Good   Accept
5     MBA        Low    Yes   Neutral   Reject
6     MCE        Low    Yes      Good   Reject
7     MSc     Medium    Yes   Neutral   Reject
8     MCE        Low     No Excellent   Reject

res.2 <- BC.discernibility.mat.RST(decision.table, range.object = NULL)
Error in BC.discernibility.mat.RST(decision.table, range.object = NULL) : 
Provided data should inherit from the 'DecisionTable' class.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have changed the heading.

Answer (score 1):

I did little research. Later I found the [website](http://dicits.ugr.es/software/RoughSets/index.php?view=Example%200%3a%20Conversion%20to%20the%20DecisionTable%20Format) where it's mentioned how to deal with the data set (external data).

The following change will solve the problem.

```
decision.table <- SF.asDecisionTable(dataset = decision.table, decision.attr = 4, indx.nominal = c(1,3:4))
```